# show text on top of graph (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, text

I made a heatmap using `ggplot2` package. I want to add some text on the top of the graph using the `annotate` function. For some reason the text were "covered" by some portions. What can I do to show the full label?

The sample data is like this:

```
data <- data.frame("group" = c("grp1", "grp2", "grp3", "grp4"), "pct"  = runif(100, min = 0, max = 100))

  data <- data %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number())
```

Code for graph is like this:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=id, y=group, fill = pct)) +
  geom_tile() +
  theme_minimal() +
  annotate("text", x = 3, y = 4.7, size = 3.2,label = "Morning") +
  annotate("text", x = 7, y = 4.7, size = 3.2,label = "Afternoon") +
  annotate("text", x = 12, y = 4.7, size=  3.2, label = "Evening") +
  annotate("text", x = 17, y = 4.7, size = 3.2, label = "Night") +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0.3, 0.45, 0.3, 0.45), "cm"))
```

The figure is attached here. 
[image]
You can see that the **morning**, **afternoon**, **evening**, and **night** text could not be displayed fully. I tried adding the margins using the `plot.margin` command, but did not work. Any idea on how to fix that?

Thanks!!

Comment: Try expanding the y scale to make room for the annotation. Also [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that's easy to answer—people could provide better help if you post more of the stuff we need to reproduce the issue (i.e. the data) and less of the stuff we don't need for the issue (theme & styling stuff)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I edited my question as you suggested. Expanding the y scale is hard to achieve because the y scale is decided by number of groups in the data set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plot.margin` sets the margins around the outside of the plot, whereas you need to make more space inside the plot. @Camille has the right idea: you need to expand the y-axis. Luckily it's simple: just pass the `expand` argument to `scale_y_discrete`.

`expand` just adds extra space to the sides of the axis, so it doesn't matter that your data is discrete (unlike using `ylim`). If you want to define the extra space in more detail (for example, to only add space to the top), passing `expand_scale` to the `expand` argument (thanks @Camille!) lets you define the extra space on each of the 4 sides individually. It also lets you add either an absolute or relative amount of space. The syntax is a bit weird, so check `?expand_scale` to see the argument names:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=id, y=group, fill = pct)) +
    geom_tile() +
    theme_minimal() +
    annotate("text", x = 3, y = 4.7, size = 3.2,label = "Morning") +
    annotate("text", x = 7, y = 4.7, size = 3.2,label = "Afternoon") +
    annotate("text", x = 12, y = 4.7, size=  3.2, label = "Evening") +
    annotate("text", x = 17, y = 4.7, size = 3.2, label = "Night") +
    scale_y_discrete(expand = expand_scale(mult = c(0, 0.3)))
```

[image]

Comment: Just to add to this: the most recent `ggplot2` added `expand_scale`, which you can use to expand by an addition and/or multiplication term for more fine-tuned & intuitive adjustment

Comment: Thanks! how can I just add extra space above instead of adding space to both above and the bottom? (I want the number id stay at the original place).

Comment: I've updated the answer. `expand_scale` gives you more control. @camille Thanks for the suggestion!